# Finding a pattern multiple times between start and end patterns python regex

Tags: python, regex

i am trying to find a certain pattern between a start and end patterns for multiple lines. Here is what i mean:

i read a file and saved it in variable File, this is what the original file looks like:

File:

```
...
...
...
Keyword some_header_file {
   XYZ g1234567S7894561_some_other_trash_underscored_text;
   XYZ g1122334S9315919_different_other_trash_underscored_text;
}
...
...
...
```

I am trying to grab the **1234567** between the g and S and also the **1122334**. The some_header_file block can be any number of lines but always ends with **}** 
So i am trying to grab exactly 7 digits between the g and the S for all the lines from the "Keyword" till the "}" for that specific header.

this is what i used:

```
    FirstSevenDigitPart = str(re.findall(r"Keyword\s%s.*\n.*XYZ\s[gd]([0-9]{7})[A-Z][0-9]{7}.*\}"%variable , str(File) , flags=re.MULTILINE))
```

but unfortunately it does not return anything.. just a blank []
what am i doing wrong? how can i accomplish this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can there be multiple `Keyword...` blocks?

Comment: Also, by `7 digits between the g and the S for all the lines from the "Keyword" till the "{"` do you actually mean `...till the "}"`? There aren't any numbers between `Keyword` and `{`

Comment: Does it work for you if you change `flags=re.MULTILINE` to `flags=re.DOTALL` and `.*` to `.*?`?

Comment: You can't do this with 1 regex with regular python _re_ engine.  If using the _regex_ module you could do it with 1 regex using the \G construct.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Yes there are multiple Keyword blocks in the file, each with a differenet set of XYZ pattern numbers.. also you are right i corrected the "}" sorry.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew following your recommendation i am able to obtain only the first pattern (on the first XYZ line) but not the second one..  which .* did you mean i need to replace? i replaced them all str(re.findall(r"Keyword\s%s.*?\n.*?XYZ\s[gd]([0-9]{7})[A-Z][0-9]{7}.*?\}"%variable , str(File) , flags=re.DOTALL))

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/iEJ8pn/1

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks Wiktor but it still matches only the first line :( it doesn't capture the second XYZ line.

Comment: @mohanadelnokaly What you want to do can only be achieve with 2 steps using `re`: 1) findall all the `Keyword\ssome_header_file\s*{([^{}]*)}` occurrences (get Group 1), 2) findall `XYZ\s[gd]([0-9]{7})[A-Z][0-9]{7}` patterns in the matches. You may get everything with  1 regex if you use PyPi regex module, but it might look too cumbersome.

Comment: Do you want me to post this solution?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes please do! Thank you very much! Also instead of the text "some_header_file" how can i use the string result of a previous findall expression? i tried %s but did not work

Comment: See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52615677/3832970). If it works, let me know what I need to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may read your file into a `contents` variable and use

```
import re

contents = "...\n...\n...\nKeyword some_header_file {\n   XYZ \ng1234567S7894561_some_other_trash_underscored_text;\n   XYZ \n1122334S9315919_different_other_trash_underscored_text;\n}\n...\n...\n..."
results = []
variable = 'some_header_file'
block_rx = r'Keyword\s+{}\s*{{([^{{}}]*)}}'.format(re.escape(variable))
value_rx = r'XYZ\s[gd]([0-9]{7})[A-Z][0-9]{7}'
for block in re.findall(block_rx, contents):
    results.extend(re.findall(value_rx, block))

print(results)
# => ['1234567', '1122334']
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/Tsh9f1).

The first regex (`block_rx`) will look like `Keyword\s+some_header_file\s*{([^{}]*)}` and will match all the blocks you need to search for values in. The second regex, `XYZ\s[gd]([0-9]{7})[A-Z][0-9]{7}`, matches what you need and returns the list of captures.

Comment: Thanks!! yes it works but i don't understand the {([^{}]*)} part? how does that work? also is there a way to make the regex work with only 1 XYZ line? it detects 2 lines and upwards correctly and returns the pattern numbers, but if i keep only 1 line it doesn't detect it.

Comment: @mohanadelnokaly 1) [It works with one `XYZ` line](https://ideone.com/MJQJ0r), 2) `{([^{}]*)}` matches a `{`, then captures into Group 1 any zero or more chars other than `{` and `}` (with the negated character class `[^{}]*`) and then just matches `}`. `re.findall` only returns a list of captures.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the simplest way here will be to use two expressions and run it in two steps. There is a little example. Of course you should optimize it for your needs.

```
import re
text = """Keyword some_header_file {
XYZ g1234567S7894561_some_other_trash_underscored_text;
XYZ g1122334S9315919_different_other_trash_underscored_text;
}"""

all_lines_pattern = 'Keyword\s*%s\s*\{\n(?P<all_lines>(.|\s)*)\}'
first_match = re.match(all_lines_pattern % 'some_header_file', text)
if first_match is None:
    # some break logic here
    pass
found_lines = first_match.group(1)
print(found_lines) # '    XYZ g1234567S7894561_some_other_trash_underscored_text;\n    XYZ g1122334S9315919_different_other_trash_underscored_text;\n    '
sub_pattern = '(XYZ\s*[gd](?P<your_pattern>[0-9]{7})[A-Z]).*;'
found_groups = re.findall(sub_pattern, found_lines)
print(found_groups)  #   [('XYZ g1234567S', '1234567'), ('XYZ g1122334S', '1122334')]
```